How do I fix the error while trying to use datetime.strptime to convert a string to a datetime object?
date_str = "2024-04-19 15:30:00"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

I attempted to convert a string to a datetime object using the datetime.strptime() method in Python. I expected the method to parse the string according to the specified format and return a datetime object. However, I encountered an error regarding the format string.

You need to tell us the error

If you did not import datetime from datetime you will get a NameError exception. If you imported datetime (only) you'll get an AttributeError exception.

Your code is incomplete, please provide a fully reproducible code and the error.
Below a complete Python3 code to use the strptime method.
Notice the first line, it imports the datetime class from the datetime module.
from datetime import datetime

date_str = "2024-04-19 15:30:00"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(datetime_obj)


I think this is the only plausible issue they are facing but, without clarification, I'm not sure it covers all bases. There might be trailing whitespace or something. However, to avoid this potential issue, I always use import datetime as dt so that it's completely unambiguous with dt.datetime. It serves the purpose of reducing keystrokes while also showing the module it's bound to
